# Number of text response in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am new to Dialog flow and trying to build product search. So for that i have many text responses. While doing this my number of text response reached to 30.

[image]

As you can see in screenshot it reached till 30 and i didn't find any option to write another text response. So clicked on Add Message Content and added new text response. But now when i query something it gives me multiple response.

[image]

So my question is:
1) Is there any way to increase number of text response(30) size. Or it is limitation.

2) If there in no way to resolve above issue. How can i get only single response as it is giving me two response from both text response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try everything in one single intent. Break into multiple to avoid complex scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Text responses are available in all platforms. 
Limitation-1: Your agent can send up to 10 sequential text messages in response to a user input (assuming no other message types are defined in the intent).
Limitation-2: You can add 30 variations to each text message response.

So, the answer to your question, there's no way, you can exceed this limit either in Standard or Enterprise edition. Secondly, what you're doing is adding a number of text messages when you reached a limit (30) while adding variations. You can resolve this issue either by deleting number of text messages or by creating different intents for different responses.

When you add variations, api.ai will randomly choose any one of those 30 responses written by you & show it to a user. You have multiple such text messages & so api.ai randomly chooses one response from each text message & so you're getting multiple responses. Hope this helps.